# jquery mobile, redirect to same page with popup success message after form processed with process.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-mobile

I have a form that submits then sends information to email using the PHP email function in process.php. That part works fine but I  cannot get the redirect(to the same page) after the form is submitted to process.php. I can redirect back to the same page using header on the process.php but then I don't have a popup success message. I tried using Jquery.mobile.Changepage but did not get it to work.

My question is- how can I redirect in Jquery mobile to the same page after the form is processed in process.php? I then need to add a popup success message.

Is mobile.changePage the best way to do it in this situation?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv="content-type">
    <title>My Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>

      <div data-role="page" id="one">
 <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Hitch Fox </h1>
               </div>
        <form id="myForm" action="process1.php" method="POST">


          <div data-role="fieldcontain"> <label for="Email"><em> * </em>
              Email:     </label> <input name="email" id="email" value="" required="true"

              type="email"> </div>
          <div data-role="fieldcontain"> <label for="verifyEmail"><em> * </em>
              Verify Email: </label> <input name="verifyemail" id="verifyemail"

              value="" required="required" type="email"> </div>
          <br>
          <div data-role="fieldcontain"> <label for="GPSlat"><em> * </em>
              GPS Lat: </label> <input name="GPSlat" id="GPSlat" value="" type="text">
          </div>
          <br>
          <div data-role="fieldcontain"> <label for="GPSlong"><em> * </em>
              GPS Long: </label> <input name="GPSlong" id="GPSlong" value="" type="text">
          </div>
          <br>
          <input value="SetGPS" id="SetGPS" type="button">
          <div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="LicensePlate"><em> * </em>License
              Plate: </label> <input name="LicensePlate" id="LicensePlate" value=""

              required="true" type="text"> </div>
                <button id="submit">Submit</button>
               </form> <!--/fieldcontain-->
        <div data-role="footer">
          <h4>Hitch Fox</h4>
        </div>
      <!--/page--> </div>

      <!-- Start of second page -->
<div data-role="page" id="two">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Hitch Fox</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>Your location was successfully sent to your email.</p>       
        <p><a href="#one">Back to page 1</a></p>    
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Hitch Fox</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->





      <script type="text/javascript">


                    var lat, lng;

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position)
{ 
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lng = position.coords.longitude;
    console.log( lat + ":" + lng);
});

// ...

$("#SetGPS").click(function()
{
    $("input#GPSlat").val(lat);
    $("input#GPSlong").val(lng);
});
          </script>

<script type="text/javascript">


$("#submit").submit(function()
{
    $.mobile.changePage("../index.html", {allowSamePageTransition: true, transition: "slideup"});
      </script>


      </body>


</html>
```

process.php

```
<?php     

$Email         = $_POST['email'];
$GPSlat        = $_POST['GPSlat'];
$GPSlong       = $_POST['GPSlong']; 
$LicensePlate  = $_POST['LicensePlate'];


$subject  = 'Your last GPS Location';
$message  = "Your last GPS location was - latitude: $GPSlat longitude: $GPSlong and you were picked up by vehicle license: $LicensePlate"; 


mail ( $Email, 'Your geolocation', $message);

//**header("location: http://example.com")**//
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting your entire code into the same page (including your mail handler), then using `action=""` instead? That stands to work. In conjunction with an `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` condition and naming your submit button to `name="submit"`

Comment: ...You also could use `echo "<a href='index.html' rel='external'>Click here to continue</a>";` type of thing, if `mail()` is successful. The `rel='external'` part is important, if you're going to go that route. Those are two options I can think of.

Comment: Thanks fred, that may work I have not yet tried, and I will, but i really want to do the redirect/reresh using jquerymobile.